# postgresql get list of unique list with order by another table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, distinct

Tables:

```
#leads
id | user_id |created_at | updated_at 

#users
id | first_name

#todos
id | deadline_at | target_id
```

I want to get unique list of leads between two dates(deadline_at) with ordering by todos.deadline_at desc

I do:

```
SELECT distinct(leads.*), todos.deadline_at
FROM leads
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = leads.user_id
LEFT JOIN todos ON todos.target_id = leads.user_id
WHERE (todos.deadline_at between '2015-11-26T00:00:00+00:00' and '2015-11-26T23:59:59+00:00')
ORDER BY todos.deadline_at DESC;
```

This query returns right ordered list but with duplicates. If I use distinct or distinct on with leads.id, then postgresql requires me use it in order by - In that case I got wrong ordered list.

How do I can achive expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't really need the users table.
Maybe try this?

```
Lead.joins("INNER JOIN todos ON leads.user_id = todos.target_id")
    .where("leads.deadline_at" => (date_a..date_b))
    .select("leads.*, todos.deadline_at")
    .order("todos.deadline_at desc")
```

Comment: `joins` will not remove the duplicates, it will mimic the raw sql result. Only eager_load does that

Comment: sorry, but this is just my query with active record. It doesn`t change anything

Answer (score 0):

It seams that you're confusing the result of a sql table with joins and the same result after ActiveRecord treatment on an association.

I presume `Lead` `has_many :todos, through: :user`  so you can do this :

```
Lead.eager_load(:todos).
     where("leads.deadline_at" => (date_a..date_b)).
     order("todos.deadline_at")
```

No need to apply `distinct` or whatever, ActiveRecord will sort out the `leads` from the `todos`and you'll have them in the right order with no duplicates. The raw sql result however will have plenty of duplicates.

If you want to achieve something similar in sql alone, you can use `distinct` or `group by` on `leads.id`, but then you'll lose all the `todos` it "contains". However you can use aggregate function to calculate/extract things on the "lost todo data".

For example :

```
Lead.joins(:todos).
     group("leads.id").
     select("leads.*, min(todos.deadline_at) as first_todo_deadline")
     order("first_todo_deadline")
```

Notice that `todos` data is only available in the aggregate functions (min, count, avg, etc) since the todos are "compressed" if you wish in each lead!

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: This example just shows the problem. Actually, eager_load might be helpful  in a simple case, but in real case I have to build query which depends on params(about 5). Ordering might based on todos.deadline_at or\and another joined tables which can be combined. That`s why I want to common solution in plain sql. But thank u for trying to help.

Comment: if you want to combine scopes with params in a robust object oriented way I suggest the [siphon gem](https://github.com/charly/siphon)